# Scrapy: How to apply settings from settings.py file

Tags: python, scrapy

I have specified the names of external files in my `settings.py` file, I would like to import these on start up. But when I run it, I get the error: `AttributeError: 'MySpider' object has no attribute 'settings'`. How do I import on start up of the spider?

The code I have so far is:

```
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):

    name = 'MySpider'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        super(MySpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.crawl_behaviour = FileOps.get_crawl_behaviour(self.settings.attributes.get('CRAWL_BEHAVIOUR'))

        self.rules = (

            Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=self.crawl_behaviour), follow=True),

        )
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

```
from scrapy.conf import settings


self.crawl_behaviour = settings['CRAWL_BEHAVIOUR']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this :

```
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings

class MySpider(Spider):
    name = "MySpider"
    allowed_domains = ["example.com"]
    start_urls = ['https://www.example.com/']

    def __init__(self, query='', *args, **kwargs):
        super(MySpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        p_setting = get_project_settings()
        self.start_urls = ['https://www.example.com']
        self.query = query
        self.crawl_behavior = p_setting.get("CRAWL_BEHAVIOUR")
```